# Работа с формами Builder 6 C++

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте!

Я использую Builder C++ 6 (в нём пишу курсовик) и возникла проблема: в программе 2 формы - главная (`Form1`) и зависимая (`Form2`).

Когда я из `Form1` открываю `Form2`, то всё нормально, но после закрытия `Form2`, `Form1` становится нерабочим (просто окно висит и всё, ничего не работает).

Проблема в том, что на `Form2` поставлен сторонний ActiveX (рисует графики), и если его убрать полностью с `Form2`, то всё ок. Подскажите что-нибудь)

Comment: Если наличие компонента ActiveX вызывает описываемую проблему, то надо выяснить, как корректно закрывать форму, содержащую этот компонент.

Comment: Почему Вы не пользуетесь "родным" и могучим TChart? Он создан специально, чтобы рисовать графики и не только.

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался. Для корректной работы необходимо было при закрытии onClosed высвобождать память, выделенную под переменную ActiveX.

Answer (score 2):

из комментариев

> Спасибо, я разобрался.
>
> Для корректной работы необходимо было при закрытии onClosed высвобождать память, выделенную под переменную `ActiveX`.
>
> [stream2006](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5259/stream2006) 3 янв '12 в 14:45